# Obtaining deviations from set google maps route?

Tags: android, google-maps

We would have all used the google maps app on android, so my question is little relevant to that.

In the gmaps for android app, when I choose a driving route, the route gets displayed on the map with voice and text commands. Suppose I deviate from that path, it recalculates the route and alerts me saying follow the original route.

So my question is, can we do this in the google maps API that is provided for android in our own app? If so what is the best followed approach.

My use case goes like this: I have a user who will start his journey to a set of client hotels, and if the transit he takes deviates I simply have to alert him saying he is following a wrong route or he has to follow the modified route. Kind of a security feature.

Comment: I am working on that as well in my app. I haven't found any API to detect the off route.  I am doing this with maths which is a pain i m going  through now. So I would like to know how others approach this

Comment: Are you calculating the polyline to current latlng distance and checking for deviations? In that case that would be pain and it would also mean there is a performance constraint.

Comment: Can 't you keep on checking the route from the Current Location of GPS and the destination at regular intervals and show the new route every set interval(if user is on track, the route will be the same)? If user deviates, the new route will be calculated. But still don't know how to get that alert of route change.